# Incompatible repository declarations using pattern design but only in server in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application in my local environment and in a production server. This application have a controller called ArticlesController with this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Core\Controllers\CoreController;
use App\Admin\Requests\ArticlesRequest;
use App\Admin\Interfaces\ArticlesRepositoryInterface;

class ArticlesController extends CoreController
{
    /**
     * @var ArticlesRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $articleRepository;

    public function __construct(ArticlesRepositoryInterface $articleRepository)
    {
        $this->articleRepository = $articleRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = $this->articleRepository->all();

        return view('admin.articles.index')->with(compact('articles'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.articles.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \App\Admin\Requests\ArticlesRequest $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function store(ArticlesRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();

        $article = $this->articleRepository->create($data);

        return redirect()->route('articles.edit', $article)->with('successMessage', 'Article created! Now you can edit the article with new information');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(int $id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $article = $this->articleRepository->find($id);

        return view('admin.articles.edit')->with(compact('article'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \App\Admin\Requests\ArticlesRequest $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function update(ArticlesRequest $request, int $id)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();

        $this->articleRepository->update($data, $id);

        return redirect()->route('articles.index')->with('successMessage', 'Article updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->articleRepository->delete($id);

        return redirect()->route('articles.index')->with('successMessage', 'Article deleted!');;
    }

}
```

How you can see, this controller uses ArticlesRepositoryInterface. This is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Interfaces;

use App\Admin\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

interface ArticlesRepositoryInterface extends BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
    * @return Collection
    */
    public function all(): Collection;

    /**
    * @param array $data
    * @return Article
    */
    public function create(array $data): Article;

    /**
    * @param array $data
    * @param int $id
    * @return int
    */
    public function update(array $data, int $id): int;

    /**
    * @param int $id
    * @return int
    */
    public function delete(int $id): int;

    /**
    * @param int $id
    * @return Article
    */
    public function find(int $id): ?Article;
}
```

Also, I have a provider that I use to instantiate the repositories with this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Admin\Interfaces\BaseRepositoryInterface;
use App\Admin\Interfaces\ArticlesRepositoryInterface;
use App\Admin\Interfaces\FilesRepositoryInterface;
use App\Admin\Repositories\BaseRepository;
use App\Admin\Repositories\ArticlesRepository;
use App\Admin\Repositories\FilesRepository;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(BaseRepositoryInterface::class, BaseRepository::class);
        $this->app->bind(ArticlesRepositoryInterface::class, ArticlesRepository::class);
        $this->app->bind(FilesRepositoryInterface::class, FilesRepository::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The code of the BaseRepository is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Repositories;

use App\Admin\Interfaces\BaseRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class BaseRepository implements BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Model
     */
    protected $model;

    /**
     * @param Model $model
     */
    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    /**
    * @return Collection
    */
    public function all(): Collection
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }

    /**
    * @param array $data
    * @return Model
    */
    public function create(array $data): Model
    {
        return $this->model->create($data);
    }

    /**
    * @param array $data
    * @param int $id
    * @return int
    */
    public function update(array $data, int $id): int
    {
        return $this->model->where('id', $id)->update($data);
    }

    /**
    * @param int $id
    * @return int
    */
    public function delete(int $id): int
    {
        return $this->model->destroy($id);
    }

    /**
    * @param int $id
    * @return Model
    */
    public function find($id): ?Model
    {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }
}
```

And finally, the code of the ArticlesRepository is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Repositories;

use App\Admin\Interfaces\ArticlesRepositoryInterface;
use App\Admin\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use App\Admin\Repositories\BaseRepository;

class ArticlesRepository extends BaseRepository implements ArticlesRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Article
     */
     protected $article;

    /**
     * @param Article $article
     */
    public function __construct(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    /**
    * @return Collection
    */
    public function all(): Collection
    {
        return $this->article->all();
    }

    /**
    * @param array $data
    * @return Article
    */
    public function create(array $data): Article
    {
        return $this->article->create($data);
    }

    /**
    * @param array $data
    * @param int $id
    * @return int
    */
    public function update(array $data, int $id): int
    {
        return $this->article->where('id', $id)->update($data);
    }

    /**
    * @param int $id
    * @return int
    */
    public function delete(int $id): int
    {
        return $this->article->destroy($id);
    }

    /**
    * @param int $id
    * @return Article
    */
    public function find($id): ?Article
    {
        return $this->article->find($id);
    }
    
}
```

It works perfectly in my local environment, but, is strange, because in the remote server, with exactly the same code, it throws an error:

Declaration of App\Admin\Repositories\ArticlesRepository::create(array $data): App\Admin\Models\Article must be compatible with App\Admin\Repositories\BaseRepository::create(array $data): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using the repository pattern for this in the first place? It has its uses, but IMHO, in this case, it doesn't achieve anything other than what your Models already provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All function declarations should be exactly the same, including the return type declarations:

**ArticlesRepositoryInterface:**

```
public function create(array $data): Article;
```

**BaseRepository:**

```
public function create(array $data): Model
```

**ArticlesRepository:**

```
public function create(array $data): Article;
```

`App\Admin\Models\Article` and `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` cannot be used both.

Perhaps this doesn't throw an exception locally because of a different PHP version?

Note: you might want to consider to extend all the repositories from a single `BaseRepository`.